# Nodejs ailed to lookup view "home" in views directory "/views"

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am new to nodejs and I am getting the following error.
`Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "/views"`
I am running the app via a service file. The service file starts the app but I get the above error.  However when I start the app using `nodejs app.js` I do not get the failed error and the app works normally.

app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes');
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.get('/starwars/',routes.home);
```

routes file.

```
var moviesJSON = require('../movies.json');
exports.home = function(req,res){
   var movies = moviesJSON.movies;
   res.render('home',
   {
     title:'Star Wars Movies.',
     movies: movies,
     //movies:['Episode 1','Episode 2','Episode 3']
   }
 );
};
```

I've tried changing the routes location to `../routes` but that is giving me a bad gateway error.  So I am stumped.

service file

```
User=webuser
Group=webgroup
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs /home/pi/examples/nodeapp/star_wars_movie_app/app.js
```

Comment: Fixed.  Since I am new to node I wasn't aware that I have to set the views directory.  added `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));` and everything works. I am unsure why I didn't need to add that line when running via command line with `nodejs app.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following line to `app.js`
`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`